# Qt Designer не работает компоновка

Tags: qt-designer, pyside2, layout

Делаю общую компоновку виджетов по горизонтали, в предпросмотре в дизайнере всё работает и растягивается как нужно. Но при запуске в PyCharm все виджеты сваливаются в кучу в левый верхний угол (будто и вовсе нет никакой компоновки), что делаю не так?
Использую Qt Designer 5.15.2 и PySide2 5.15.2.1
Вот как это выглядит в дизайнеере
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И вот так при запуске
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если не использовать общую компоновку, то всё в порядке, но хочется иметь адаптивный ui.
Ссылка на модуль UI - https://disk.yandex.ru/d/P-nGv6BsN7IjTQ

Код, которым запускаю:

```
import sys
from main import Ui_Form
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
class Main_Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Main_Window()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Пожалуйста, опубликуйте модуль .ui, который вы сделали в Qt Designer и опубликуйте код, который вы запускаете, и который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Добавил ссылку и код в основное сообщение, спаисбо

Comment: Хм, если в дизайнере сделать ui по типу Main_window ( а я случайно выбрал widget), то всё работает оО

Comment: Да, вам надо создать другой класс, который `наследуется от соответствующего виджета`, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.